# ask with getView method in gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I want to load images each one for each gridview element but it loads me only last image for all elements of gridview. How can I solve it ? My example images are like a50.jpg

Here is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    String s = Integer.valueOf(items.get(position).id_of_field).toString();
        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("a" + s + i,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        view.ivTowar.setImageResource(resourceId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `getView` method you are creating `View` for a specific element, not for all elements at all. So the correct code shouldn't contain `for` loop.

**EDIT** The correct code should be like that, without `for` loop (and you are trying to parse a string to integer and then get a string again):

```
String s = items.get(position).id_of_field;
int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("a" + s + position,
            "drawable", context.getPackageName());
view.ivTowar.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: could you give me an example how can I make it ?

Comment: can you please specify what are you trying to do? why are you trying to make a name via `"a" + s + i`?

Comment: yes, of course. my images are naming like a51.jpg where a is a simple string s is the value of category id look at this String s = Integer.valueOf(items.get(position).id_of_category).toString(); and i is an iterator of category's items list.size()

Comment: I've got my gridview with elements and I want to load unique image each  one for element in my gridview.

Answer (score 0):

`position` is already giving a position of cell which is being viewed. Remove your loop. For code and detail about custom gridview follow [this](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100)

or google for good tutorial

Comment: can I make it more dinammicly without array ?

Comment: yes only if you can calculate your data/(image name) dynamically, so you don't need to use any data structure to save your data/(image name)